# gdb not executing breakpoint commands during while loop

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

I have a simple C program (shown below), that calls a function `g` 5 times in a loop, and inside the function `g`, it calls `f` 10 times in a loop (so `f` is called 50 times altogether). I am trying to write a `gdb` script (also shown below) that:

1. Puts a break point at `g`
2. Runs until `g` is first called
3. Sets breakpoint commands for the breakpoint in `g` so that the next time the breakpoint in `g` is reached, `gdb` exits
4. Sets a breakpoint in the function `f`
5. Enters a while-loop, which does something every time `f` is reached, and then continues (this has to be a while loop rather than a set of breakpoint commands, because this is a minimal example of a more complex case, where I have multiple `step`/`finish`/`continue` commands every time the breakpoint in the inner function is reached, which is not possible with breakpoint commands)

What I observe is that the breakpoint in the inner function `f` is reached, but when `gdb` reaches the breakpoint in `g` for the second time, it doesn't execute the commands I have set for `g` (IE `gdb` doesn't exit). The program continues executing and continues to the next time the function `f` is called, even though if I type `info break` at the `gdb` prompt, `gdb` shows the commands I have set for the breakpoint in `g`.

My questions:

1. Why are my breakpoint commands in the function `g` not being executed, even though `gdb` prints out every time it reaches the breakpoint in `g`, and `info break` prints out the commands associated with `g`?
2. How do I change my `gdb` script so that when the breakpoint in `g` is reached for the second time, `gdb` exits?
3. Maybe, as a solution to the previous question, is there some way to check which breakpoint has been reached in the while-loop, and exit if it is the breakpoint in `g`?

Below are my simple C program and `gdb` script:

### Simple C program

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;

void f() {
    printf("in f(), i = %i\n", i++);
}

void g() {
    printf("in g()\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        f();
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        g();
    }
}
```

### `gdb` script

```
break g
run

delete
break g
commands
printf "gdb: in g\n"
quit
end

break f
continue
while 1
    printf "gdb: in f\n"
    continue
end
```

Comment: Looks similar to gdb [bug 28606](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28606).

Comment: Looks about right, thanks @ssbssa !

Answer (score 0):

I have a sort-of-hacky solution, which works in this case (and also in the more complex case I am interested in, for which the question above is a minimal reproducible example). But it won't necessarily work in every case, EG when there is no valid counter variable in a higher stack frame, so I'm going to post it here but not accept it as an answer, while I wait for a more general solution.

The trick is as follows: at the start of the while-loop, go up the stack-frame and look at the `j` counter variable in the `main` function, and exit `gdb` as soon as `j > 0` (which means that `g` has been called more than once). Example `gdb` script:

```
break g
run

delete
break f
continue

while 1
    printf "gdb: in f\n"
    frame function main
    if j > 0
        quit
    end
    continue
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2. How do I change my gdb script so that when the breakpoint in g is reached for the second time, gdb exits?

You can use this `blah.txt` script file:

```
    break g
    ignore 1 1
    run
    quit
    y
```

Which is basically saying:

- Break on `g` function.
- Ignore that breakpoint 1 time.
- Run the program.
- Quit.
- Yes, I really want to quit.

Build your `blah.c` file with: `gcc -g -o blah blah.c`

Run it with: `gdb -x blah.txt blah`

Output:

```
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x1196: file blah.c, line 9.
    in g()
    in f(), i = 0
    in f(), i = 1
    in f(), i = 2
    in f(), i = 3
    in f(), i = 4
    in f(), i = 5
    in f(), i = 6
    in f(), i = 7
    in f(), i = 8
    in f(), i = 9
    
    Breakpoint 1, g () at blah.c:9
    9       void g() {
    A debugging session is active.
    
            Inferior 1 [process 181] will be killed.
    
    Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

---

If you want to do some work whenever you hit `f` and `g` breakpoints, this other script may work:

- Set a boolean flag, `break_g_hit_before`, to false.
- Define your set of commands for breakpoint on `g` as:
  print I'm in `g`;
  check if `break_g_hit_before` is true and, in that case, exit from gdb;
  otherwise, set `break_g_hit_before` to true, and continue.
- Define your set of commands for breakpoint on `f` as: print I'm in `f` and continue.
- Run.

```
    set $break_g_hit_before = 0
    break g
    commands
        printf "*** gdb: in g\n"
        if $break_g_hit_before
            quit
            y
        end
        set $break_g_hit_before = 1
        continue
    end
    break f
    commands
        printf "### gdb: in f\n"
        continue
    end
    run
```

Output:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1196: file blah.c, line 9.
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1169: file blah.c, line 5.

Breakpoint 1, g () at blah.c:9
9       void g() {
*** gdb: in g
in g()

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 0

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 1

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 2

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 3

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 4

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 5

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 6

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 7

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 8

Breakpoint 2, f () at blah.c:5
5       void f() {
### gdb: in f
in f(), i = 9

Breakpoint 1, g () at blah.c:9
9       void g() {
*** gdb: in g
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 219] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I want to do some work whenever I hit `f` and `g` breakpoints, but as I mention in the question, this has to be a while loop rather than a set of breakpoint commands, because this is a minimal example of a more complex case, where I have multiple `step`/`finish`/`continue` commands every time the breakpoint in the inner function is reached, which is not possible with breakpoint commands. See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html: "Any other commands in the command list..."

Comment: OK, cool. If you changed your question showing what you're trying to achieve with a simple program, I'm sure we'd be able to help. On the other hand, I believe this can and should be achieved without `while` loops. I fear that loop is what is stopping the breakpoint on `g` to be hit a second time.